# Developing Windows Store Application

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I need to create windows store application using c#.I need Pre-requisite(**like OS version and VS studio Version**) for developing the App.

Any Suggestion regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-express-windows-8?CR_CC=200395106) on a Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 OS.
Then create new project and find Visual C# -> Store Apps. Choose your desire project template (Universal, Windows or Windows Phone) and there you go.